# Vim/Ag: files whitelist in AgFromSearch

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ag

I am using vim with `Ag.vim`(silver-searcher) and i came across a problem.

the Ag plugin defines Ex mode commands such as *`:Ag`* and *`:AgFromSearch`*.
but while *`:Ag`* lets me pass options to the **shell's** `ag` command such as `-G` which lets me whitelist files, *`:AgFromSearch`* doesn't let me..

so my question is - is there any pretty solution to this? or should i just imitate the way the plugin implements *`:AgFromSearch`* with *`:Ag`* and pass through it the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ag.vim is deprecated; you should consider moving back to using Ack.vim. 
The maintainer of Ack.vim is open to supporting the Ag community.

The :AckFromSearch allows for passing extra options like the -G. You first must configure the Ack.vim to use Ag, by adding this to .vimrc:

```
let g:ackprg = 'ag --vimgrep'
```

And, then you can do :AckFromSearch like the following:

```
:AckFromSearch -G '.*py'
```

Since moving back to the Ack.vim plugin, I use this feature quite frequently and have mapped ,* to :AgFromSearch in vim.